# AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'r2_score'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm testing machine learning methods on a csv file with kickstarter project data. But even though I can get "**accuracy score**", I get the following error when I try to get "**r2 score**". What would be the reason?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

veri = pd.read_csv("kick_rev.csv")

veri = veri.drop(['id'], axis=1)
veri = veri.drop(['i'], axis=1)

y = np.array(veri['state_num'])
x = np.array(veri.drop(['state_num','usd_goal_real','deadline','launched','country'], axis=1))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)

DTR = DecisionTreeRegressor()
DTR.fit(X_train,y_train)
ytahmin = DTR.predict(x)
DTR.fit(veri[['goal','pledged','backers','usd_pledged','usd_pledged_real','category_num','category_main_num','currency_num','country_num']],veri.state_num)
accuracy_score = DTR.score(X_test,y_test)
a = np.array([5000,94175.0,1,57763.8,6469.73,13,6,0,0]).reshape(1, -1)
predict_DTR = DTR.predict(a)
r2 = DTR.r2_score(X_test, y_test)

print(accuracy_score)
print(r2)
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'r2_score'
```

Comment: This time I came across this error `ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (9!=1)`

Comment: ``r2_score `` measures how well your model predicts, so the input is ``y_true, y_pred``. In your case, you feed the input and output label, which is not expected.

Comment: sorry to join late actually I made mistake there since I was focusing your error only not the parameter that you are passing I agree with the answer given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R2 Score is between predicted and actual value. So you can't use Train features and prediction for comparision

```
r2_score(y_pred, y_true)
```

You can use this link for more clarification

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html